# How does the LSTM implementation in Keras work

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am going through the code in `recurrent.py` for the class `LSTMCell`  (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py)

Does that class calculate the hidden and carry states for a single time step?

Where can I find the code that deals with the unwinded network, i.e that goes from timestep to timestep?

I am trying to compute the output of each gates at each time step for a single example. So far, I can extract the weights, biases from a trained network and compute the activations by following the code from line 1828 to 1858. In particular:

```
i = self.recurrent_activation(x_i + K.dot(h_tm1_i,
                                          self.recurrent_kernel_i))
f = self.recurrent_activation(x_f + K.dot(h_tm1_f,
                                          self.recurrent_kernel_f))
c = f * c_tm1 + i * self.activation(x_c + K.dot(h_tm1_c,
                                                self.recurrent_kernel_c))
o = self.recurrent_activation(x_o + K.dot(h_tm1_o,
                                          self.recurrent_kernel_o))
```

My input has shape: input(seq_length, nb_dim). So to properly calculate the output of each gate, should I do something like:

```
for step in range(seq_length):
  input_step = input[step, :]
  x_i = np.dot(input_step, kernel_i) + bias_i
  i = recurrent_activation(x_i + np.dot(h_tm1_i, recurrent_kernel_i)
  <<< repeat for other gates >>>
  <<<compute cell hidden state/carry state>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where can I find the code that deals with the unwinded network, i.e that goes from timestep to timestep?

This logic is done by [`keras.backend.rnn`](https://keras.io/backend/#rnn) function ([`recurrent.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L601)):

```py
last_output, outputs, states = K.rnn(step,
                                     inputs,
                                     initial_state,
                                     constants=constants,
                                     go_backwards=self.go_backwards,
                                     mask=mask,
                                     unroll=self.unroll,
                                     input_length=timesteps)
```

The `step` is basically the call of a cell...

```py
def step(inputs, states):
  return self.cell.call(inputs, states, **kwargs)
```

... which in case of LSTM cell computes the `i`, `f`, `c` and `o` gates, as described in your question, and evaluates the output and state tensors from them.

If you're using tensorflow backend, you can find the actual loop that iterates over input series in [`keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2622).

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. One more thing, I checked `tensorflow_backend.py` (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L2622). The code related to the unrolled rnn (at prediction) is from line 2662 to 2670. right? Would you know what imported file  contains the code for the function `step_function()`. Thank you